# How to Save State of Page when navigate to another page

Tags: xaml, savestate

Windows phone store app
I have 2 page. In the page 1, I navigate to page 2. And page 2 have many checkbox.
I check someone and navigate to page 1. How I can save state page 2 when I navigate again ?

Answer (score 0):

There's a page property called "NavigationCacheMode" explained in the following link.
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/hh771188.aspx
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/windows.ui.xaml.controls.page.navigationcachemode.aspx

Quoting:

> You can specify that a page be cached by using the
>   NavigationCacheMode property. In the constructor of BasicPage1, set
>   NavigationCacheMode to Enabled